# parseInt duplicates object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

After

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].dummyProp = parseInt(data[i].dummyProp);
}
```

i get double property name:

```
data: Array[1]
  0: Object
    dummyProp: NaN
    dummyProp: ""
```

Image from Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

Can someone explain that?

Comment: Could you give us the raw data object? Or even better create a fiddle with your code? Try this: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour in the JS-console...
`>>> var data = new Array()

undefined

>>> data.push({dummyProp: "123"});

1

>>> data

[Object { dummyProp=

"123"

}]

>>> for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { data[i].dummyProp = parseInt(data[i].dummyProp); }

123

>>> data

[Object { dummyProp=

123

}]`

Comment: The only explanation I can imagine is that the property name contains some non-printable character.

Comment: Couldn't there be a Object.dummyProp AND a Object['dummyProp'] (like the behaviour of a dictionary) ? And in that case maybe Chrome's console doesn't display the quotes ?

Comment: Example for my previous comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SbW6r/.

Comment: @Ricola3D: No, all property names are converted to strings anyway. `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` are equivalent (which you can easily find out using `var obj = {}; obj.foo = 'bar'; alert(obj['foo']);`).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to recreate the issue with no luck, but I might have an idea that you can test:

Try this:

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(data.[i].hasOwnProperty('dummyProp')){
    data[i].dummyProp = parseInt(data[i].dummyProp);
  }
}
```

( Just to check that the object really has the property, ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty )

In addition, please supply the original data object for us, so we can check if there's something else. It would really help users that wants to help you :)